# VS2019 ,NET Core 5.0 Razor Pages ~ Unable to launch browser could not connect to debug target

Tags: visual-studio, razor-pages

I have **two** .NET Core 5.0 Razor Page Model projects, almost identical, reside in the same solution. Have not been running for almost 4 months.

Now when I wish to make some changes. **One** of the project cannot run in debug mode. I am always getting the following error

[image: Error when launch with debug]

> {"tag":"dap.receive","timestamp":1625537078095,"metadata":{"connectionId":0,"message":{"type":"request","command":"launch","arguments":{"WebRoot":"xxxx\ApmtWeb\wwwroot","rootPath":"xxxx\ApmtWeb\wwwroot","__workspaceFolder":"xxxx\ApmtWeb\wwwroot","runtimeExecutable":"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe","runtimeArgs":[],"sourceMaps":true,"url":"http://localhost:5031/","trace":{"logFile":"yyyy\Temp\visualstudio-js-debugger.txt"},"port":54798,"launchUnelevated":false,"projectGuid":"cca052fc-e9e7-44d5-8299-28928d665223","userDataDir":"yyyy\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16.0_e9805624\WebTools\F17440DA_BBDA0153","breakOnLoad":true,"smartStep":true,"skipFiles":[],"showAsyncStacks":true,"timeout":10000,"cleanUp":"onlyTab","name":"Visual Studio launch configuration override","type":"pwa-msedge","request":"launch","continueOnDisconnect":true},"seq":2}},"level":0}

The xxxx and yyyy were obscured due to privacy

My launch settings

> "ApmtWeb": {
> "commandName": "Project",
> "dotnetRunMessages": "true",
> "launchBrowser": true,
> "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5031",
> "environmentVariables": {
> "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
> }
> }

I am able to see my web page if I manually type in the URL **http://localhost:5031**, before the above error shows and forcing it to shutdown.

There is not such setting inside my entire solution as **http://localhost:54798**, and I can't find any reference to **54798** even if I do a global search.

Comment: I had the same problem. Reinstalling VS solved the problem.

Comment: @MajidShahabfar thanks for the answer. Actually my problem automagically gone today. Without doing anything.

Comment: This is a bug in VS2019. and infact i have it now. I had spent a day trying to fix it and then automagically  it went away,  i did nothing. VS has been bug free for weeks now, but this morning its back like a cold sore. So time for a VS repair. This was for a .net 4.5 MVC project, but can be anything. Sway from Chrome to Edge then it works fine.

Comment: I am having this.  Brand new hosted blazor project just stopped working with exactly this behavior.  Created another identical project and it works.  Updated VS to 16.11.3 but still getting the error.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is not necessary to delete the whole .vs folder, just go to .vs/project/ and delete the debuggerConfiguration -... json file.
It is important to close any browser windows that have remained open before running the project again, otherwise it will recreate the debuggerConfiguration -... json file but it still gives an error.

[.vs/project/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AzYhJ.png)

Comment: Whereas the most popular answer above works it's like cutting off the leg because of a clout in the toe, this answer should be upvoted, because it's much more precise! Thanks @diago.escada!

Answer (score 19):

When I learned from one of the comments that this is a VS bug, I immediately tried the following:

1. Close solution
2. Remove all .vs directories from your project
3. Launch solution again

Worked for me.
Saved me from actually reinstalling VS ;-)

Comment: Just go with this solution.

Comment: This is the way to go. Fixed for me.

Comment: This problem came back this morning, and I am managed to prove this works.

Comment: This worked after but I had to make the browser from the previous debug session was closed.

Answer (score 14):

You can also disable the debugging of JS by VS, vis  the Options menu so you just debug in Chrome (F12). Unchecking this feature, press F5, then stop it, the check it again also fixes the problem.

Such black magic :/
[image]